# Given a string, find the count of possible codes that string can generate using Python

Tags: python

If a=1, b=2, c=3,....z=26. I want to find the count of possible codes that string can generate using Python

For example:

```
get_combination('12')
Output: 2
// The possible decodings are "AB", "L"

get_combination('121')
Output: 3
// The possible decodings are "ABA", "AU", "LA"

get_combination('1234')
Output: 3
// The possible decodings are "ABCD", "LCD", "AWD"
```

Here is the code for that. but the time complexity is more. Can someone have simpler solution than this

```
def get_combination(string):
    def get_branchs(string):
        if not string or len(string) == 1:
            return 0
        if string[0:2] <= '26':
            if '0' not in string[1:3]:
                return 1 + get_branchs(string[1:]) + get_branchs(string[2:])
            else:
                return get_branchs(string[2:])
        else:
            return get_branchs(string[1:])
    return 1 + get_branchs(string)
```

Comment: how do you get the `decodings` exactly?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: `12` can be interpreted as `1` (a) and `2` (b) --> `AB` or as `12` (l) --> `L`.

Comment: What do you mean with the phrase *"but the time complexity is more"*? As I see it your algorithm has the optimal time complexity already. It could maybe be optimised, but not in terms of time complexity (except for the use of `[:]`).

Comment: @TimPietzcker The `'1234'` example is the one I do not fully get. Would the combinations be **4** if it was `'1218'` instead (to include the 12-18?)?

Comment: If the input is '12'. The possible decodings are "AB", "L", means a=1, b=2. one combination is "AB" and another is L=12, We  have 2 combination so answer is 2

Comment: @Debaprasad Well, the `get_combination` function does nothing if its whole body is the recursive `get_branchs`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, the last line returns something ;-)

Comment: the plural of branch, isn't it _branchEs_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest form I've got:

```
def get_num_codes(number):
    if not number:
        return 1
    # If you want to allow for "stray zeros" at the end remove this if block
    if number == "0":
        return 0
    count = get_num_codes(number[1:])
    if number[0] != "0" and len(number) > 1 and number[:2] <= "26":
        count += get_num_codes(number[2:])
    return count
```

Performance of both versions is comparable:

```
%timeit get_combination("123412432414324231123412")
>>> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 ms per loop
%timeit get_num_codes("123412432414324231123412")
>>> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

As Trincot commented, you could save time on the string slicing by passing an offset to your `get_branch` function, so you don't have to pass `string` or a `string` slice.

So here's my modified version, only using an offset as a parameter for the internal `get_branch` function:

```
def get_combination(string):
    def get_branchs(offset=0):
        if len(string)-offset <= 1:
            return 0
        if string[offset:2+offset] <= '26':
            if '0' not in string[1+offset:3+offset]:
                return 1 + get_branchs(1+offset) + get_branchs(2+offset)
            else:
                return get_branchs(2+offset)
        else:
            return get_branchs(1+offset)
    return 1 + get_branchs()
```

There are some remaining slicing to compare to 26 and to check if `0` is in the sub-string. Testing against indexes would be an alternative, but I'm unsure of how this would behave when indexes are out of bounds (slicing doesn't mind, index access does)

Note: I hope to be on-topic when answering, maybe codereview would be best for this kind of question & answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following observations:

- There can be invalid sequences: a 0 should always be preceded by either a 1 or a 2. If there is a violation of this rule, a 0 should be returned (or an exception raised)
- All minimal sub sequences in the input that can increase the number of combinations start with a 1 or 2. So, for example, a string that starts with a 7 will produce just as many combinations as the same input with that 7 removed.
- The sub sequences of interest (that allow multiple combinations) can be isolated from each other, since they also have an end: take for instance "212121212127": this sequence cannot be extended to the right with one more character which would allow *more* combinations, since the ending 7 can never be combined with whatever the next character is in the input.
- Let the definition of a "relevant sub sequence" be: any sub sequence that would return 2 or more (count of combinations) if regarded as a separate input, and that would return a lesser value if made one character shorter (be removing one character from either end of it), and would *not* return a greater value if made 1 character longer at either side of the sub sequence (i.e. not *any* character, but as a sub sequence from the input of course). The regular expression to match such relevant sub sequences is

  ```
  [12]*?(?:[3-6]|1[3-9]|(?=.0|$))
  ```
- The number of combinations represented by one relevant sub sequence is given by the following recursive form (where `n` is the length of the sub sequence):

  ```
  C(n) = 1 when n == 1
       = 2 when n == 2
       = C(n-1) + c(n-2) when n > 2
  ```

  This is the Fibonacci series (shifted with one index position, as the true Fibonacci have `Fib(2) = 1`, but that is just a detail).
- So, if we would first find the longest relevant sub sequence, we would know how many Fibonacci numbers to generate (and not more!), and will have to do that generation only once. Then we can just take the product of the Fibonacci numbers corresponding to the lengths of the sub sequences.

Here is the commented code implementing those ideas:

```
import re
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce # For Python 3.x

def get_combination(string):
    def fib_to(n):
        fibs = [1, 1] # Real Fibonacci would need [0, 1], but we want fib[2] to be 2.
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            fibs.append(fibs[-1] + fibs[-2])
        return fibs

    # Detect an invalid sequence, where a 0 occurs without a 1 or 2 preceding it  
    if re.search(r"(?<![12])0", string):
        return 0
    # Find all sub sequences where a variation is possible
    sequences = re.findall(r"[12]*?(?:[3-6]|1[3-9]|(?=.0|$))", string)
    if not sequences:
        return 1
    # Get the sizes of all these sequences; it is all we need to know
    sizes = [len(seq) for seq in sequences]
    # Generate Fibonacci numbers up to the maximum needed:
    fib = fib_to(max(sizes))
    # Take the product of the sizes for each of the sequences
    return reduce(mul, [fib[size] for size in sizes], 1)

tests = [ # inputs combined with expected outputs
    ["", 1],
    ["2", 1],
    ["12", 2],
    ["121", 3],
    ["1234", 3],
    ["2121", 5],
    ["210", 1],
    ["210210", 1],
    ["22102210", 4],
    ["219219", 9],
    ["07", 0],
    ["507", 0]
]

for test in tests:
    res = get_combination(test[0])
    if res != test[1]: 
        print("Error - Input: '{}' Output: {} Expected: {}".format(test[0], res, test[1]))
    else:
        print("OK - Input: '{}' Output: {}".format(test[0], res))
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/HbaA/7)

Notice the boundary cases that are tested. Your code fails several of these tests.

At the time of writing none of the answers produce a correct result for input "07" (which should return 0), and kashif's answer is the only one that only fails that test.

Here is the output of the test for each of the answers at the time of writing: [repl.it](https://repl.it/HbaA/9)

Comment: I'm not sure you have defined your use cases right. "07" and "507" have one valid code, and "22102210" has definitely more than 4 (I count 7 [[22, 10, 22, 10], [22, 10, 2, 2, 10], [22, 1, 02, 2, 10], [2, 21, 02, 2, 10], [2, 2, 10, 22, 10], [2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 10], [2, 2, 1, 02, 2, 10]] but my function gets 10, not sure who is wrong...)

Comment: But the logic should be that if you encode letters you get the input string. There are no letters that generate 07 or 507..

Comment: Well to be honest is hard to tell, since the OP didn't give examples with zeros. I was assuming the logic was that there was a mapping from number to letter, and so `7` and `07` would be the same. But your interpretation is just as reasonable I guess.

Comment: btw from `22102210` I was missing [22, 1, 022, 10], [2, 21, 022, 10] and [2, 2, 1, 022, 10] haha but yeah only in my version of the story

Answer (score 0):

There is an opportunity for [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) here: the number of combinations for a given suffix of your string (so the last N characters) is fixed regardless of what comes before.

So you can work your way from end to beginning of the string and store the number of combinations for each suffix.
This should lead to a drastically reduced runtime.

```
def get_combinations(input):
    store = [ 0 for _ in input ]
    store[len(input)-1] = 1
    store.append(1)

    idx = len(input) - 2
    while idx >= 0:
        can_make_double = input[idx:idx+2] <= '26'
        if can_make_double:
            store[idx] = store[idx+2] + store[idx+1]
        else:
            store[idx] = store[idx+1]
        idx = idx - 1
    return store[0]

for input in ['12', '121', '1234']:
    print("%s: %d" % (input, get_combinations(input)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be broken down into two parts if we start from the end of the string instead of the beginning :

1. If the last digit!=0 , repeat the procedure for the remaining digits, and add the count to the result.
2. If the last two digits are less than 27, repeat the procedure for the remaining digits and the add the count to the result.

More info can be found here : [Count Possible Decodings of a given Digit Sequence](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-decodings-given-digit-sequence/)

Here is the Python version of the C code using Dynamic Programming mentioned in the link :

```
def decodings(digits):
    n_digits =  len(digits)
    count_table = {}
    for i in range(0,n_digits+1):
        count_table[i]=0
    count_table[0] = 1
    count_table[1] = 1

    for i in range(2,n_digits+1):
        #Case 1: If the last digit!=0 , repeat and add the count to the result.
        if digits[i-1] > '0':
            count_table[i] = count_table[i-1]
        #Case 2 : If the last two digits are less than 27, repeat and the add the count to the result.
        if digits[i-2] == '1' or (digits[i-2] == '2' and digits[i-1] < '7'):
             count_table[i] += count_table[i-2]

    return count_table[n_digits]

print decodings('121')
```

Time complexity is O(n) and Space complexity is O(n) where 'n' is the number of digits in the input.